# Access files at new location using old file paths

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess, slug, migration, directory

I have a bunch of posts that contain images with urls that follow this pattern:

`https://example.com/example_directory/files/2019/04/file.png`

I've imported the posts into a new install of wordpress on the same domain with file structure where the files now reside at

`https://example.com/new_directory/2019/04/file.png`

Because "example_directory" is now a category slug, I cannot simply update the new directory structure to mirror the old one.

How can I make the files inside `new_directory` appear when my browser tries to visit urls at `directory/files`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I've found the solution. I add the following

```
RewriteRule ^example_directory/files/(.*) new_directory/$1
```

to my WordPress .htaccess rules like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^example_directory/files/(.*) new_directory/$1
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

I couldn't get it working before and I think the key was moving the new `RewriteRule` directive to the line directly following `RewriteBase /`

Comment: Make sure you add your custom `Rewrite` commands before the `# BEGIN WordPress` otherwise it'll get removed when you update permalinks.

Comment: "the new `RewriteRule` directive to the line directly following `RewriteBase /`" - The order of the directives with respect to `RewriteEngine` and `RewriteBase` does not matter (surprisingly). The important bit is that the directive is _before_ the other directives that now following (ie. the WordPress front-controller). As Sunil pointed out, you should place your custom directive _before_ everything - at the top of the file (you do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` or `RewriteBase` directives).